# Restrict data for multiple users

Tags: yii, yii2-advanced-app

I add multiple users as teacher. And I create a table where every teacher update his data that is documents etc.,but when another teacher login he can also view that data how user to restrict to show that to other users?

Comment: Hi, when you put a question, you need to set details...like snippet of your code, determine place issue....etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about [Yii](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en), and how you can use it.

For your case you can read this: [add condition](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/yii2-add-where-condition-to-model-for-every-find/82710)

For your question you can do this in your action in [controller](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers):

0) ensure that user is logged in: `\Yii::$app->user->isGuest || //redirect to login page` or via [Access control filters](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#access-control-filter)

1) get user id from user. (`\Yii::$app->user->identity->id`)

2) set this id in teacher document query. like `andWhere(['teacher_id' => $userId]);`

```
public function actionViewDoc()
    {   $userId = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $model = TeacherDoc::find()->andWhere(['teacher_id' => $userId]);

        return $this->render('viewDoc', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

This will resolve your issue.

UPD: For more advanced solutions you could use:

1) [Access control filters](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#access-control-filter)

2) [RBAC](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#rbac).